# How do we split SPSS dataset into 2 dataset to perform internal validation?

Tags: cross-validation

I want to split my data set into two files, 50% of random cases in each file. I would like to use the first set as a training set and the second one for testing my prediction model.

**Following is an example:** 
10 cases (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), I want to split it into 2 files with 5 random cases in each file (1,3,6,7,9) and (2,4,5,8,10).

How can I do this using Data>Select Cases option? 
I am able to generate a single set of 50% random cases but how do I test the remaining 50% of cases. SPSS gives an output of only 1 file

Comment: This Q is both off-topic and also unclear (for example, may the two subsamples intersect by their case composition or not?).

Answer (score 1):

Data -> Select Cases. Choose "Random sample of cases". You can either specify approximately 50% of the cases (SPSS Syntax below) or a specific number. You should tick the option in the Output box to "Copy selected cases to a new dataset" and name the new dataset (this is also in the syntax below).

```
DATASET ACTIVATE DataSet1.
DATASET COPY  dataset2.
DATASET ACTIVATE  dataset2.
FILTER OFF.
USE ALL.
SAMPLE  .50.
EXECUTE.
DATASET ACTIVATE  DataSet1.
```